# How to use spring security with activity

Tags: spring-security, activiti

I use Spring Security 3 for my project, and now I want to use Activiti to model the business work flow. As we know, spring security has its own database schema including the tables like "User","Role","Authority" and acivity also has some of its own schema.How can i integrate these two.Any idea.Am a beginner to activity please explain me in detail.Thank you

Answer (score -2):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/253901/Getting-Started-Spring-Security) you can find some information..